# Replace occurrences of two characters with each other in a string

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, nsstring

I have a problem where I need to invert two characters within a string. For example, if my string is "a*b/c" and I want to replace occurrences of * with / and / with *. I want the  resulting string to be "a/b*c".

Using the method `stringByReplacingOccurrenceOfString:` doesn't work because I don't want the first round of replacements to affect the second:

```
string = @"a*b/c";
[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"*" withString:@"/"];
[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"*"];
```

This results in "a*b*c", which is not what I want. Does anybody know an efficient way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string = @"a*b/c";
[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"*" withString:@"&"];
[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"*"];
[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"/"];
```

Comment: Hm, nice try. What if he has other `&` characters in that string in a first place?

Comment: I do like this as a solution provided there is no use of "&" / "other arbitrary character"

Comment: If `&` can occur in the string, just make up any string you're sure won't be there, such as `tHiS_sTrInG_wIlL_nEvEr_OcCuR_iN_mY_sTrInG`

Comment: Heck, just use any non-normal character, like ú or ę or į

Answer (score 2):

Use an `NSScanner` to move through the string and substitute each character as it is found. This way, all substitutions are done in one pass and you're never looking at a position twice.

```
NSMutableString * fixedUpString = [NSMutableString string];
NSScanner * scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:origString];
NSCharacterSet * subCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"*/"];

while( ![scanner isAtEnd] ){

    // Pick up other characters.
    NSString * collector;
    if( [scanner scanUpToCharactersInSet:subCharacters intoString:&collector] ){
        [fixedUpString appendString:collector];
    }

    // This can easily be generalized with a loop over a mapping from
    // found characters to substitutions
    // Check which one we found
    if( [scanner scanString:@"*" intoString:nil] ){

        // Append the appropriate substitution.
        [fixedUpString appendString:@"/"];
    }
    else /* if( [scanner scanString:@"/" intoString:nil] ) */  {
        [fixedUpString appendString:@"*"];
    }
}
```

`fixedUpString` now contains the substituted content.

As I noted in the comment, this can be generalized very easily to any number of substitutions:

```
NSDictionary * substitutions = @{ @"a" : @"z", @"b" : @"y", ... };
NSCharacterSet * keyChars = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:[[substitutions allKeys] componentsJoinedByString:@""]];

...

// Check which one we found
for( NSString * keyChar in [substitutions allKeys] ){

    if( [scanner scanString:keyChar intoString:nil ){
        [fixedUpString appendString:substitutions[keyChar]];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to have a go at this without using the intermediary `&` character, and though this is certainly more convoluted, this also appears to work:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    NSString *s = @"1*2/3*4*5*6*7*8/2";

    NSArray *stars = [s componentsSeparatedByString:@"*"];
    NSMutableArray *slashes = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *star in stars)
    {
        [slashes addObject:[star componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"]];
    }

    NSMutableArray *newStars = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSArray *slash in slashes)
    {
        [newStars addObject:[slash componentsJoinedByString:@"*"]];
    }

    NSString *newString = [newStars componentsJoinedByString:@"/"];

    NSLog(@"%@", newString);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 1/2*3/4/5/6/7/8*2

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on a solution, since I could not find a builtin method that would do what you are looking for.

```
NSString *string = @"a*b/c";
NSDictionary *swapings = @{@"*" : @"/", @"/" : @"*"};
NSString *newString = [self swap:swapings inString:string];
NSLog(@"'%@' became '%@'", string, newString);

# ... somewhere in self :

-(NSString *)swap:(NSDictionary *)swapings inString:(NSString *)string {
    NSMutableArray *letters = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
        NSString *letter = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
        [letters addObject:letter];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<letters.count; i++) {
        NSString *letter = [letters objectAtIndex:i];
        for(NSString *token in [swapings allKeys]) {
            if ([letter isEqualToString:token]) {
                letter = [swapings valueForKey:token];
                break;
            }
        }
        [letters replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:letter];
    }

    return [letters componentsJoinedByString:@""];
}
```